# Displaying tree in a table with drag and drop functionality and persisting the data from angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, json, html

I am new to Angularjs. Please help me with the below requirement.Screen shot shared. Please have a look at it. Description is as follows, using angularjs I want to create a tree in table it should have the following features:

1. It should have drag and drop option to update the tree. Changes should be persisted.
2. Tree contains checkbox.
3. Editing the node names using a double click and persisting that change.

If you have any example with same or similar functionality, can you please share it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the drag and drop requirement, I'd suggest you look into diagraming frameworks that utilize HTML + SVG. One that I worked with, and would suggest, is jointjs. The data structure that they employ to connect all of their elements is a graph, but I'm certain you can apply some order to have it mimic a tree. They also have out-of-the-box searching and sorting algorithms that you can overlay on top of your data.

link: http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.0/joint.html

Hopefully this helps. Good luck!